# Dockerfile volume with database - using volume for mutable user-servicable parts

Tags: mysql, docker, volume, dockerfile

This is taken from the official docker website [Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) ..

> **VOLUME**
>
> The VOLUME instruction should be used to expose any database storage
>   area, configuration storage, or files/folders created by your docker
>   container. You are strongly encouraged to use VOLUME for any mutable
>   and/or user-serviceable parts of your image.

What is meant by using volume for any mutable and user serviceable parts of the image?  Are there times when I should/shouldnt and use a volume for databases?  If so why? Is this where you mount the actual data contents of the database separate from the docker container..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but I found an example which might help. From the book "Build your own PAAS with Docker" by Oskar Hane, where he creates a container used only to host files for other containers, such as a MySQL container:

*There is a VOLUME instruction for the Dockerfile, where you can define which directories to expose to other containers when this data volume container is added using `--volumes-from` attribute. In our data volume containers, we first need to add a directory for MySQL data. Let's take a look inside the MySQL image we will be using to see which directory is used for the data storage, and expose that directory to our data volume container so that we can own it:*

```
RUN mkdir –p /var/lib/mysql 
VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]
```

Comment: thanks for the update.  Why would we expose the volume?  is this so we dont have to load the data?

Comment: From the same book:  A data volume lets you share data between containers, and the data inside the data volume is untouched if you update, stop, or even delete your service container. A data volume is mounted with the –v option in the docker run statement:
`docker run –v /host/dir:container/dir` You can add as many data volumes as you want to a container, simply by adding multiple –v directives.  ...the containers that get data volumes passed into them don't know about it... it works just as if it were writing to the local filesystem. You can override existing directories inside containers...

Comment: Other people are telling me to never use a VOLUME directive in a Dockerfile (is allowed in a docker-compose). I'm trying to reconcile that with what I'm learning here